# Not able to read attribute from python dictionary

Tags: python, json, debugging, dictionary, logging

I have the below dictionary object which is created by reading each line from a log file. Each line in the log file contains data in json format as indicated by the content of "parsed_obj". How do I get rid of this error ? I am not able to read the attribute of the dictionary even though the dictionary contains the attribute. Anything I have to do to handle the encoding?

```
>>> parsed_obj
{u'eventType': u'type1', u'eventDesc': u'desc1'}

>>> parsed_obj.eventType
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'eventType'

>>> type(parsed_obj)
<type 'dict'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python dictionary access value using `.['KEY']`.
If u want to access how u wrote like

```
>>> parsed_obj.eventType
```

then write new class. like

```
class NewDict(dict): 
    __getattr__ = dict.__getitem__
    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
```

and use it

```
>>> parsed_obj = NewDict(parsed_obj)
```

Comment: yeah. Thanks. i mixed javascript with python